# How to recover the property TileID a SecondaryTile?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In my app, I create a SecondaryTile. As Arguments and TileID I insert the ID property of my object. How do I retrieve this value in the page when I press on App.xaml.cs SecondaryTile and how do I navigate to another page I want?
This is the code:

```
    SecondaryTile t2 = new SecondaryTile();
    t2.TileId = muss.ID.ToString();
    t2.Arguments = muss.ID.ToString();
    string nome = "Open ARTE";
    t2.DisplayName = nome;

    t2.VisualElements.Square150x150Logo = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}", fileName));
    t2.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;
    await t2.RequestCreateAsync();
   CreateLiveTileSecondary();
```

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve it from the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs.TileId` property - [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.tileid.aspx)